# Unable to load the teachable machine model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

Getting a error while loading a model(.h5)

the error is below:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 208, in from_config
return cls(**config)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\depthwise_conv2d.py", line 118, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\base_depthwise_conv.py", line 106, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 263, in **init**
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\NanoPix--ISS\3.Teachable machine\Using_teachable.py", line 6, in 
model = load_model("keras_model.h5")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 183, in load_model
return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py", line 133, in load_model_from_hdf5
model = saving_utils.model_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 326, in from_config
layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 326, in from_config
layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 528, in from_config
return functional_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 509, in functional_from_config
process_layer(layer_data)
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 489, in process_layer
layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 504, in deserialize_keras_object
deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(cls_config)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Ananconda\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 210, in from_config
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 1, 'mode': 'fan_avg', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'seed': None}}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

```
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Load the model
model = load_model("keras_model.h5")

# Load the labels
with open("labels.txt", "r") as file:
    class_names = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

# Load and preprocess the image
image_path = "data//images2//img ("+str(1)+").jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image_array = np.asarray(image)
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.5) - 1
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# Make a prediction
prediction = model.predict(data)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
class_name = class_names[index]
confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

# Print prediction and confidence score
print("Class:", class_name, "Confidence Score:", confidence_score)
```

This is my python code and u i am using the following versions:
[versions used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJmpL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to change the interpreter, the code works fine with those particular versions.